# Symfony : how to set init data on login

Tags: symfony, local-storage, symfony-2.8

I'm facing a dilemna as well as an optimization problem :

In my Symfony 2.8 application, I have custom settings and other business logic data to load (from database tables, not from SF parameters) that a logged in user can be needed to use at different pages.

At first those data where scarcely needed, so i loaded them only when the page required it. But now as the application grows, i need them more often.

So i was thinking about loading them when the user logs in, and save them as localStorage on client side because cookies are too small.

But i'm not sure how to best do it.
I have a login success handler, that allows to redirect on the correct page when user is successfully logged.

For the moment i have this one :

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $router;
    protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(Router $router, AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    /**
     * What to do when user logs in.
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $response = null;

        if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            //an admin is redirected towards this page
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('my_back_admin'));
        } else if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            //a user is redirected towards this page
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('my_back_user'));
        }
        //redirect to any last visited page if any
        $key = '_security.main.target_path';
        if ($request->getSession()->has($key)) {
            $url = $request->getSession()->get($key);
            $request->getSession()->remove($key);
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

So i was thinking about adding a setInitialData() method in which i would get all the settings i need and modifying onAuthenticationSuccess :

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $response = null;
    //retrieve array of data to be set in the init  
    $toBeSaved = $this->setInitialData();

    if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        //an admin is redirected towards this page
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('my_back_admin', ['initdata'=>$toBeSaved]));
    } else if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        //a user is redirected towards this page
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('my_back_user', ['initdata'=>$toBeSaved]));
    }
    //redirect to any last visited page if any
    $key = '_security.main.target_path';
    if ($request->getSession()->has($key)) {
        $url = $request->getSession()->get($key);
        $request->getSession()->remove($key);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url, ['initdata'=>$toBeSaved]);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

And then on the main template, i would retrieve that data

```
{% for paramName, paramValue in app.request.query %}
    {% if paramName == 'initdata' %}
    <div id="initdata" data-init="{{paramValue|json_encode}}"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and add a javascript block with something like :

```
<script>
    if ($('#initdata').length > 0){
      localStorage.removeItem('initdata');
      localStorage.setItem('initdata', JSON.stringify($('#initdata').data('init')));
    }
</script>
```

But this method doesn't seems right : i'm not sure this is the best way to do it.

And furthermore, since these are sent in a redirect, the data are shown in the query string, which is not ideal :(

Comment: Step stop rendering the data on the server side and embrace javascript and load resources using asynchronous ajax calls. Whole code you pasted is over-engineered, unmaintanable and untestable.

Answer (score 0):

<s>This will not fly as by having multiple parameters you create multiple `<div>` elements with identical ID = `initdata`. Subsequent `jQuery` selector will only capture the first one (afaik).</s>

I see that you indeed send params via query string. This takes care of multiple value, but this also exposes your user setting in user URL, doesn't it? If it does, it has security vulnerability all over the wall. Remember, such URLs are persisted in your browser's history.

Instead, I suggest you create a separate controller action `/_get_user_settings` which you will call via `AJAX` `GET`. Server will serve `JSON` response which you can save to your `localStorage` with little or no problem at all.

Hope this helps...

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "multiple div". I indeed have multiple parameters, but they are all children of initdata, set in the onAuthenticationSuccess method. So  even there were other parameters sent, only this one is of interest to me and thus there is only one div created. This said, your idea of having a ajax call could be interesting : i could only set my initdata to true and if it is set, i could call an ajax to retrive this initial data i need. The problem in that case would be : what if the user change page before the data is properly saved.

Comment: Agree, you would need a way to block navigation until browser receives user settings. This is usually extremely fast, but still...

Comment: On the plus side, your suggestion allows to clearly separate the task : let the method manage the redirection, and have another method take care of the data